# dropdownchanged event not firing in usercontrol in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a dropdownlist in a usercontrol as shown below

```
   <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlLanguage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:dropdownlist>
```

my selectedchanged event is not getting fired even once

in code behind

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  //dt - is list of languages availbale in DB
 //value[0]-contains lang currently to be binded to dropdownlist based
 //remaining values (values [1]) to are to be populated to textbox
  LoadModuleInfo(dt,values)
}

     private void LoadModuleInfo(System.Data.DataTable dtLanguages, string[] values)
    {
        this.txbxModuleName.Text = values[1];

        this.ddlLanguage.DataSource = dtLanguages;
        this.ddlLanguage.DataTextField = "language_description";
        this.ddlLanguage.DataValueField = "language";
        this.ddlLanguage.DataBind();

        // set up selections on the screen 

        this.ddlLanguage.SelectedIndex = this.getIndex(dtLanguages, values[0]);

    }

  protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
          //get new values ( values[0] and values[1])
         LoadModuleInfo(dtLanguages, values);
     }

 protected int getIndex(DataTable dt, string recordId)
  {
    int intCt = 0;

    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dr[0].ToString() == recordId)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            intCt++;
        }
    }

    return intCt;
}
```

i have wriiten the above code, but selectedchanged event is not fired for dropdownlist control available in USERCONTROL.

Please help.

Comment: LoadModuleInfo(dtLanguages, values; <--

Comment: LoadModuleInfo(dtLanguages, values; Closing ")" is missing.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, but problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

If you page not refreshed at all .. most probably you have a javascript error in the page

Comment: page_load is happening but selected_change event is not firing

Comment: Please make sure that the values of the drop down list are different 
for example if your drop down binds a list like the following list
"Apple" "1"
"Orange" "1"
"Banana" "1"

this will not fire the event

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove below line from your code and try

```
this.ddlLanguage.DataValueField = "language";
```

***or***

change this too **language** to **language_description**